# when use the Cypress.config how could change the env parameter?

Tags: cypress

when i want to config the pageLoadTimeout, i could use following code, but how about configuring the env parameter?

```
Cypress.config('pageLoadTimeout',100000)
cy.log(`pageLoadTimeout默认值是：${Cypress.config('pageLoadTimeout')}`)

Cypress.config('env',{"cookie1": cookies[7]['value']}) //not work.
cy.log(`当前环境变量为${JSON.stringify(Cypress.env())}`)

Cypress.config.env('cookie1','bbbbb') // report error
cy.log(Cypress.config.env('cookie1'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
cy.log(`当前环境变量为${JSON.stringify(Cypress.env())}`); // before setting
Cypress.env({
  cookie1: 33
});
cy.log(`当前环境变量为${JSON.stringify(Cypress.env())}`); // after setting
```

[image: Screenshot from my test]

Comment: yes, it works, appreciate you answer. BTW, do you know how to restore the data in cypress.json permanently as i want to share the cookie for all the cases. but do not want to get the database in.

Comment: Regarding your question: If you want to globally set the env variable in `cypress.json` file , you can add under 'env' as `"env": {  "var1": "Some Variable" ... }`. Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Options

Comment: Or you can have a separate `cypress.env.json` file. Refer: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-2-cypress-env-json